# Stuck storage compartment door

Tags: chevrolet, door

I have a 2008 Chevy HHR with a stuck dash storage compartment door. I've tried to pry it open with a screwdriver and I've tried to push the obstruction out with some wire. I have no idea how to get it unstuck.

Comment: Is the issue the center dash storage bin or the passenger side glove box

Comment: @mikes It's the center dash storage bin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to push the door closed and pull the latch to see if that open it.  Sometimes if you over stuff the compartment it will close and be pushed so tightly against the door it cannot unlatch.  By pushing on the door you are relieving pressure and allowing the latch to open.